# Find quartic function given constraints

Tags: calculus, polynomials, maxima-minima, python

I have a generic quartic function

$$f(x) = a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4$$

and I want to find the values for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ such that the function has two minima at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ and one maximum at a given $x = x_e$ (which must be calculated). Other restrictions to the problem are that $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 0.5$ and $f(x_e) = 1$.

At first, it is easy to predict that $a = 0$ and $b = 0$. But I do not know how to find the other values of $c$, $d$ and $e$. Perhaps making use of Lagrange multipliers is a way, but I can't figure it out how to solve the problem this way.

I'm trying to use IPython with SymPy to solve and plot the problem, so preferably a solution showed with these packages would be great.

Comment: this problem is not very suitable for symbolic computation. It's better to try to find a solution by hand, or go for a numerical solution.

Comment: @vistidge You are right, I was trying with SymPy but got error while triying to differenciate. Anyway, any solution by hand is also well appreciated :)

Comment: Could you determine the coefficients via Vietas formulae? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: That $x=1$ is a local minimum gives you $4e+3d+c=0$. That $f(1)=1/2$ gives you $e+d+c=1/2$. That $x=0,1$ are solutions of $f'(x)=0$, tells you that $x_e=-\frac{3d+4e}{4e}$ is the remaining solution. From this and $f(x_e)=1$, you get another equation $e\frac{(3d+4e)^2}{(4e)^2}-d\frac{3d+4e}{4e}+c=\frac{(4e)^2}{(3d+4e)^2}$. From those three equations you can find the solutions.

Comment: @arugula if you know of a way to find the answer , you could write it down as an answer. Would be helpful for everybody

Comment: @arugula Thanks. Indeed I arrive to that system o equations. Now I have to find the solution. I am not that good at Álgebra, and if the system Is not linear (so I cannot build a Matrix) I don't know how solve it. At this point I am looking for using a computer to find the solutions. Any  help Is appreciated.

Comment: With the two linear equation you can eliminate two of the variables from the other equation. It looks like you get a degree 5 polynomial equation, for which which you are likely to have to use numerical methods to find a solution anyway. Therefore, just put the system in which ever software you hate the most and let it give you the solution. I put it in wolframalpha and is computes one real solution.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks! Never had heard of that formula!

Comment: @arugula Thank hoy very much!

Comment: @arugula https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lPPyGLlWnUZ6AchuZlcArT8qq-uPH-sR/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: How it's that possible? I expected to find a solution. It seems it's impossible, to plot a function with the requirements I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $f(0) = 0$, we conclude that $\color{blue}{a = 0}$. From the fact that $f$ has two local minima and one local maximum, we conclude that $\color{blue}{e > 0}$. Taking the 1st derivative of $f$, we obtain

$$f ' (x) = b + 2 c x + 3 d x^2 + 4 e x^3$$

From $f ' (0) = 0$, we conclude that $\color{blue}{b = 0}$. From $f ' (1) = 0$ and $f (1) = \frac 12$, we obtain a system of $2$ linear equations in unknowns $c$, $d$ and $e$

$$\begin{array}{rl} 2 c + 3 d + 4 e &= 0\\ c + d + e &= \frac 12\end{array}$$

Let us introduce parameter $t > 0$. Let $\color{blue}{e = t}$. Hence, $\color{blue}{c = t + \frac 32}$ and $\color{blue}{d = -1 - 2 t}$. Thus,

$$f ' (x) = (2 t + 3) x + 3 (-1 - 2 t) x^2  + 4 t x^3 = x \left( 2 t + 3 - 3 (1 + 2 t) x + 4t x^2 \right)$$

After some tedious work, we conclude that the maximum is attained at

$$x_{\max} := \frac{2 t + 3}{4t}$$

Since $f (x_{\max}) = 1$, we eventually obtain the quartic equation

$$(2 t + 3)^3 (2 t - 1) - 256 t^3 = 0$$

Using [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) to solve the quartic equation above:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> t = Symbol('t')
>>> p = (2*t + 3)**3 * (2*t - 1) - 256*t**3
>>> roots = solve(p,t)
```

Print the $4$ roots in **floating-point**:

```
>>> for r in roots:
        r.evalf()


0.401923788646684 - 0.431895218164327*I
0.401923788646684 + 0.431895218164327*I
11.6136005841302
-0.417448161423609
```

Print the **positive** root:

```
>>> roots[2].simplify()
3*sqrt(3)/2 + 3 + sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3))/2
```

Since only one root is real and positive, we conclude that the value of parameter $t$ is

$$\boxed{ \quad t = \frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{2} + 3 + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{72 + 42 \sqrt{3}} \approx 11.6136005841302 \quad }$$

Let us verify:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> t = 3*sqrt(3)/2 + 3 + sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3))/2
>>> f = (t + 1.5)*x**2 - (1+2*t)*x**3 + t*x**4
```

Let us check the derivatives:

```
>>> diff(f,x).subs(x,0)
0
>>> diff(f,x).subs(x,1)
0
>>> diff(f,x).subs(x,(2*t+3)/(4*t))
-3*(3*sqrt(3) + 7 + sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3)))*(3*sqrt(3) + 9 + sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3)))**2/(6*sqrt(3) + 12 + 2*sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3)))**2 + 4*(3*sqrt(3)/2 + 3 + sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3))/2)*(3*sqrt(3) + 9 + sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3)))**3/(6*sqrt(3) + 12 + 2*sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3)))**3 + 2*(3*sqrt(3)/2 + 4.5 + sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3))/2)*(3*sqrt(3) + 9 + sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3)))/(6*sqrt(3) + 12 + 2*sqrt(72 + 42*sqrt(3)))
```

The 3rd one is messy. In floating-point:

```
>>> diff(f,x).subs(x,(2*t+3)/(4*t)).evalf()
0.e-123
```

which is zero. So far, so good! Let us check if $f (1) = \frac 12$:

```
>>> f.subs(x,1)
0.500000000000000
```

It works! Lastly, quartic function $f$ is

$$\boxed{\quad f (x) =  \frac 12 \left( 3 \sqrt{3} + 6 + \sqrt{72 + 42 \sqrt{3}} \right) x^{4}  - \left(3 \sqrt{3} + 7 + \sqrt{72 + 42 \sqrt{3}}\right) x^{3} + \quad \\ \qquad\quad + \frac 12 \left( 3 \sqrt{3} + 9 + \sqrt{72 + 42 \sqrt{3}} \right) x^{2} \quad}$$

Plotting the graph of function $f$,

[image: plot of f]

The local maximum is attained at

$$\frac{2t+3}{4t} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \dfrac{3 \sqrt{3} + 9 + \sqrt{72 + 42 \sqrt{3}}}{3 \sqrt{3} + 6 + \sqrt{72 + 42 \sqrt{3}}} \right) \approx 0.564579455317661$$

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a for your explanation!